# How to load all orders from a specific customer in Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can we load all orders for a specified customer id in Magento2? This is how we did it in Magento1.

```
$orderCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection(); 
$lastyear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 year"));
$orders = $orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter("customer_id", 1234567890)->addAttributeToFilter('state', 'complete')->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq'  => $lastyear));
```

Answer (score -1):

Hello mike you can get all orders of specific customer in this way

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$lastyear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-1 year"));
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->getCollection()->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id', $customer_id)->addAttributeToFilter('state', 'complete')->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', ['gteq'  => $lastyear]);
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have any luck with the code sample, but was able to pull the orders with the following:  $lastyear = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("-4 year"));
$orderCollection = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Collection');
$orderCollection->addAttributeToFilter('customer_id',$customerId)->addAttributeToFilter('status','complete')->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('gteq'  => $lastyear))->load();